# VisionOS: "Spatial presentations are not permitted from popovers." while using a ColorPicker from a popover

Tags: swiftui, visionos

I'm attempting to use a `ColorPicker` from popover in VisionOS and the app throws the following exception when the user selects the color picker: **Spatial presentations are not permitted from popovers.** Other picker types (eg a list of numbers) works correctly. I've searched and haven't found a way to disable the "Spatial presentation" of the `ColorPicker`, at least not so far. I'm hoping someone has figured out how to make this work.

To reproduce, create the "hello world" VisionOS app and use the following for the `ContentView`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var popoverPresented = false
    @State var color: Color = .red
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Show Popover") {
                popoverPresented = true
            }
            .popover(isPresented: $popoverPresented) {
                ColorPicker("Color", selection: $color)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe submit a feature request sir a “color picker style” I don’t think the OS has this right now

Answer (score 0):

it only works with `.windowStyle(.plain)`. e.g

```
struct ColorPaletteApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }.windowStyle(.plain)
    }
}
```

[[image: Simluator example]]